# Remove the space between Cards

Tags: android, padding, android-cardview

I'm using a RecyclerView to store these cards it works but I want to reduce the space between cards. After adding cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" this line it reduced a bit but still it's too much. Is there a way to do this?

Card Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10sp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/lightest_black"
    app:cardElevation="16dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ripple">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sick_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sick_topic"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/productsansbold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sick_expandable_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sick_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/productsansregular"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerView layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    tools:context=".IfYoureFeelingSick">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sick_recyclerView"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InyaH.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the code snippet of your recyclerview as well?

Comment: sorry about that, I'll add it.

Comment: Try to remove the paddingTop from the LinearLayout and marginTop from the RecyclerView and see if there is any change.

Comment: I removed top and side padding and layout margins but the space between cards doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

try add `android:layout_margin="-10dp"` to your `CardView` to control unwanted spaces created by `CompatPadding` and no need to say you can replace -10 with any negative number you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="10sp"
android:layout_margin="-10dp"
.....
>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, nothing happens